# Replace an image of fabric js canvas with an hq image programmatically and recalc coord and sizes of other objects

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, image-size

I need to make a hq representation of fabric canvas objects. there are photos there with low quality that had been uploaded by the user during creation process.   I need to replace the photos with original HQ versions and then recalc coords and sizes of other objects on the canvas. As I'm going to use server side for replacing photos on fabric canvas I need nodejs to run fabric on it. 
Is it the right way to reach what I need or there is an easier solution? and if it's the right way can anybody give me a code example of fiddle please?

P.S. Using `canvas.toSvg` and then resize it with imagemagick in php didn't help cause the quality of 2000x2000 px image created from 200x200 px is totally bad.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution. you need to install nodejs server. 
1. save your canvas data to json 
2. change the path to your low quality img with the path of your hq img
3. send it to nodejs by ajax call. 
4. load canvas from json on nodejs server
5. save the final canvas to an img